# Besides the doctype and the html tag, what other markup can be outside the html head and body?

Tags: html

With an HTML document almost everything is inside the html head and body. What are all the things that can be outside of the html head and body?

Comment: Which HTML version? And BTW, it's documented: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Specifications

Comment: 4.01 and 5, thanks for the doc link i will look at that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML 4.01 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#h-7.1) specifies these three parts an HTML document is comprised of:

> - a line containing HTML version information,
> - a declarative header section (delimited by the **HEAD** element),
> - a body, which contains the document's actual content. The body
>     may be implemented by the **BODY** element
>     or the **FRAMESET** element.

---

[HTML 5 Editor Spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-root-element) specifies `html` as the root element with

> A **head** element followed by a **body**
>   element.

and `frameset` is included in the [Obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html) feature list

Answer (score 1):

Only comments and space characters.

> Documents must consist of the
>   following parts, in the given order:
>
> 1. Optionally, a single U+FEFF BYTE ORDER
>      MARK (BOM) character.
> 2. Any number of
>      comments and space characters.
> 3. A
>      DOCTYPE.
> 4. Any number of comments and
>      space characters.
> 5. The root element, in
>      the form of an html element.
> 6. Any
>      number of comments and space
>      characters.

Source: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#writing

Answer (score 0):

That should be it. You have html as parent, and head and body as children.